# Matching Confidence limits with One-Sided Hypothesis tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

I'm trying to understand (esp. the **boldfaced part**) how [**THIS ARTICLE (see p. 174, top-right corner)**](http://ww.w.statpower.net/Steiger%20Biblio/Steiger04.pdf) is suggesting  that:

"to use the confidence intervals to test a statistical hypothesis
and to maintain a Type I error rate at alpha:

1. When testing a two-sided hypothesis at the alpha
   level, use a **100(1 - alpha)%** confidence interval.

**2. When testing a one-sided hypothesis at the alpha
level, USE a 100(1 - alpha / 2)% confidence interval.**"

Comment: The article has ``100(1 - 2 alpha)`` as Antoni writes in his answer. But you confusingly have (incorrectly) ``alpha/2`` in your question.

Comment: A citation for the article which the OP mentions: Steiger JH. Beyond the F test: Effect size confidence intervals and tests of close fit in the analysis of variance and contrast analysis. Psychol Methods. 2004 Jun;9(2):164-82. doi: 10.1037/1082-989X.9.2.164. PMID: 15137887.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you generate the two-sided confidence interval with a confidence level of $95\%$ (or $\alpha_1 = 5\%$), the cut-off points (or endpoints) of the interval will leave out a probability of a type I error of $\frac{1}{2} \alpha=2.5\%$ on either end.

If you are performing a one-sided test, and want to preserve a risk $\alpha = 5\%$ of rejecting the null when it is in fact true, you will want to generate a two-sided CI with and confidence level of $90\%$ to leave $5\%$ probability at each end.

So you double the initial $\alpha_1 =5\%$ to $\alpha_2=2\alpha_1=10\%.$

Hence the quote:

> 1. When testing a two-sided hypothesis at the alpha level, use a $100(1 - \alpha )\%$ confidence interval.
> 2. When testing a one-sided hypothesis at the alpha level, use a $100(1 - 2 \alpha)\%$ confidence interval.

[image]

Comment: Antoni, I'm a bit confused. Isn't it true that when we do a one-sided test, we have one-rejection region? If yes, where do we place our rejection region under the sampling distribution?

Comment: Yes. It is true. Just imagine the area under that rejection level in red. It contains, say $5\%$, which is the probability of rejecting the null when it is true. Now picture the other end of the "bell curve" without any areas in red.

Comment: If you want to get that same area (with its cutoff point on the $x$-axis by "cheating" and actually getting two red areas...

Comment: one at either end of the curve (a $\text{mean}\pm \text{1/2 CI}$)...

Comment: ... still preserving the original $5\%$ red area that you had at the beginning, you will have to double $\alpha,$

Comment: ... so that when you divide in half... for the upper and lower bounds, you preserve the cutoff level at whichever end you are working on, leaving the same area in red as though you hadn't worked with two-sided CI's. Does it make sense?

Comment: I will upvote anyway, but let me think more, please let me get all this on paper.

Comment: Check the difference between one-sided and two-sided CI's [here, on page 33](http://amath.colorado.edu/sites/default/files/2014/02/1672850199/Week7.pdf), for example.

Comment: This is for one-side CIs right, but I'm looking for 2-sided CI used in one-sided hypothesis tests?

Comment: Right, exactly... You are "tweaking" the alpha level to get **with a two-sided CI** a **one-side hypothesis test**. You know, I like illustrations, and when I have some time later, I may include a couple of drawings.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your drawings!

Comment: I guess I got it! Really, One Picture Worth Ten Thousand Words!!

Comment: So, this is to keep the length of the arms of the CI at equal length?

Comment: I think we are now on the same page - check the illustration. Hope it helps.

Comment: Antoni, Which illustration, you mean?