# Why is the upper bound of the 95% CI infinity when using a one sample wilcoxon?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, median, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I've been calculating 95% confidence intervals around the psuedomedian in a one sample wilcoxon signed rank tests, with a "greater" alternative and the mu = 0. That is, I have been exploring whether the group pseudomedian is greater than 0. I have several difference tests using this configuration. If it's relevant, I have completed this using wilcox_test() in the rstatix package in R.

The variable is always bounded. Values can only exist between -1 and 1. The reported lower bound of the confidence interval always has a specific value (e.g., -0.0172) but the upper bound always comes out as infinity. Why is this and is it accurate? I interpret this to mean that the true value exists somewhere between the lower bound and infinity but I don't understand why it doesn't vary across different tests I complete. The pseudomedian and distribution of the data is different for each test I run.

Further, when it comes to reporting an upper bound confidence interval like this, do I report it as infinity or as 1, because I know that logically the value cannot be greater than this value.

I hope this is enough information but please do let me know if further details would be helpful.

EDIT: As requested, I've added a plot showing the distribution of the data points. Each yellow diamond represents the median. Each violin represents a different wilcoxon test performed.

[image]

EDIT 2: I should also say, the upper CI value varies if the wilcoxon is two tailed instead of one tailed, so I think it might be something to do with that?

Comment: Can you show the data or plot them?

Comment: Hi @rep_ho! Please see the above edit.

Comment: Could it be because you are doing only one sided test?

Comment: @rep_ho, I think so, but I'm not sure I totally understand the reason why beyond that.

Comment: if you do `alternative='two.sided'` will you get inf as well?

Comment: No, only with ```alternative = "greater"```

Comment: One-sided confidence intervals correspond to one-sided hypothesis tests (ie. alternative = "greater" or "less"). One end of a one-sided confidence interval is infinity. [Matching Confidence limits with One-Sided Hypothesis tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257936/matching-confidence-limits-with-one-sided-hypothesis-tests)

Comment: Thank you @dipetkov. This is really helpful and makes sense. Shame none of the links in the other post work. Big stretch, but do you know of any journal articles/textbooks covering this?

Comment: By "this" do you mean confidence intervals? Every intro stats should explain confidence intervals. The linked post does a fine job as well. I also like this online book: [Improving Your Statistical Inferences](https://lakens.github.io/statistical_inferences/confint.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dipetkov provided some helpful links to other questions with informative answers [Matching Confidence limits with One-Sided Hypothesis tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257936/matching-confidence-limits-with-one-sided-hypothesis-tests) and a textbook that covers confidence intervals well https://lakens.github.io/statistical_inferences/index.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).